# FastAI predictions of the tabular learner don’t work

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

I was trying to predict some data with the tabular learner after building a model but i get an unexpected behavior when trying to do so: all the prediction are stuck on one value with a 100% confidence. This value changes randomly, but is always one and i don’t understand how i can solve this issue. As an example, this is the confusion matrix i get when i train the model:
[image]

and this is the matrix when i try to predict the values from another dataframe:
[image]

In this pictures, the predicted value is always "uncertain_significance" but it changes randomly, but with the same only one value pattern.
For anyone who wants to see the actual code, I'll leave here the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Hybp0zAWfnhHNBXyDDt-QrQVI4zc0EE_#scrollTo=hZsLt-bdYB1V). Thanks!